# Searching on Last Decimal Place

Tags: sql

In the SQL (SQL Server 2019) database I am working, the vendor has introduced a rounding bug and I'm trying to track down all instances of this issue.

On a decimal field with 10 decimal places eg. 42.5500000001, I want to search where only the last decimal place is not equal to zero.  I'm struggling with the code on this one.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres etc

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the last value in your column from the `RIGHT` and check to see if it’s not equal to zero.

```
select * from test_table where right(test_column, 1) <> 0
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BYMeeuA_).